# How to update VSTS Files programatically (using c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application, azure-devops

I have Visual Studio Team Server and I want to edit some files programmatically, Is it possible using c#?

See image below for the folders and files that i want to get and update.
[image]

Comment: [Team Foundation Server SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that through TFS API by using C#.

1. Create workspace
2. Map files
3. Get latest files
4. Modify files
5. Check in changes

For sample code, you can refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer/) article.

On the other hand, you could achieve that through Rest API. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319758/tfs-rest-api-check-in-to-version-control) thread.

Comment: Saves my day :) Thank you