# Cannot successfully call CreatePushAsync

Tags: c#, git, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to programmatically update a file in an existing branch but I get this exception.

> The combination of parameters is either not valid or not complete.
> Parameter name: refUpdate

Here is my code:

```cs
GitRefUpdate desiredBranch = new GitRefUpdate()
{
    RepositoryId = sourceRepoGuid,
    OldObjectId = branch.ObjectId
};

GitCommitRef newCommit = new GitCommitRef()
{
    Comment = $"Update config to match new branch ",
    Changes = new GitChange[]
    {
        new GitChange()
        {
            ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Edit,
            Item = new GitItem() { Path = $"/{fileName}" },
            NewContent = new ItemContent()
            {
                Content = fileContent,
                ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText,
            },
        }
    },
};
        
GitPush push = gitClient.CreatePushAsync(new GitPush()
{
    RefUpdates = new GitRefUpdate[] { desiredBranch },
        Commits = new GitCommitRef[] { newCommit }
}, sourceRepoGuid).Result;
```

I would imagine from the error message that I'm doing something wrong with the `GitRefUpdate` object.  I've tried several different combinations of `OldObjectId`, `NewObjectId` with the SHA from the last commit of the file to the SHA of the branch itself, nothing satisfies the call to `CreatePushAsync`.

The only example I've found is in the MS samples and it creates a new branch and adds a new file.  I want to update an existing file in an existing branch.

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try TFS REST API as the steps below:

1. Get commit ID value: Request method: GET; URL [collection url]/[team project name]/_apis/git/repositories/[repository name]/commits?api-version=1.0&branch=master&$top=1
2. Update file content: Request method: Post; URL: [collection url]/[team project name]/_apis/git/repositories/[repository name]/pushes?api-version=3.0-preview.2; Content Type: application/json;

JSON data:

```
{
    "refUpdates": [{
        "name": "refs/heads/master",
        "oldObjectId": "[step 1 commit ID]"
    }],
    "commits": [{
        "comment": "Updated BuildLog.cs",
        "changes": [{
            "changeType": 2,
            "item": {"path": "/BuildLog.cs"},
            "newContent": {
                "content": "using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class BuildLog
    {
        public int count;
        public string[] value6;
    }
}
",
                "contentType": 0
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Please refer to this case for more details: [Updating a file using REST Api Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703475/updating-a-file-using-rest-api-visual-studio-team-services)

Comment: The reason I'm needing the client example is that I'm moving my REST API wrappers classes to use the C# Client libraries.  I'll see if I can use your steps and example to figure out what I need to get it working with the client library.

Comment: Kindly post your test result.

Comment: Following your example, all I had to do change RepositoryId to Name in my GitRefUpdate
GitRefUpdate desiredBranch = new GitRefUpdate()
{
    Name= sourceRepoName,
    OldObjectId = branch.ObjectId
};