# TFS JAVA SDK14.0.3 - How to fetch remote file from server and make changes and check in again

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-sdk

I have a  project in team foundation server named master-builds . the master-build  folder has a xml file named build-main.xml
i want to fetch this files from server and make some changes in it (change  the  version number ) and check in again , how  can i achieve it using TFS JAVA SDK 14.0.3 .

I tried the samples provided  in the folder but not able to achieve.

This is the code snippet to create workspace

```
public static Workspace createAndMapWorkspace(final TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc) {
    final String workspaceName = "SampleVCWorkspace" + System.currentTimeMillis(); //$NON-NLS-1$
    Workspace workspace = null;

    // Get the workspace
    workspace = tpc.getVersionControlClient().tryGetWorkspace(ConsoleSettings.MAPPING_LOCAL_PATH);

    // Create and map the workspace if it does not exist
    if (workspace == null) {
        workspace = tpc.getVersionControlClient().createWorkspace(
            null,
            workspaceName,
            "Sample workspace comment", //$NON-NLS-1$
            WorkspaceLocation.SERVER,
            null,
            WorkspacePermissionProfile.getPrivateProfile());

        // Map the workspace
        final WorkingFolder workingFolder = new WorkingFolder(
            ConsoleSettings.MAPPING_SERVER_PATH,
            LocalPath.canonicalize(ConsoleSettings.MAPPING_LOCAL_PATH));
        workspace.createWorkingFolder(workingFolder);
    }

    System.out.println("Workspace '" + workspaceName + "' now exists and is mapped"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

    return workspace;
}
```

This is the snippet to add/edit files

```
public static void getLatest(final Workspace workspace) {
    final ItemSpec spec = new ItemSpec(ConsoleSettings.MAPPING_LOCAL_PATH, RecursionType.FULL);
    final GetRequest request = new GetRequest(spec, LatestVersionSpec.INSTANCE);
    workspace.get(request, GetOptions.NONE);
}

public static File addFile(final Workspace workspace) {

    // Create the file locally
    final File newFile = new File(ConsoleSettings.MAPPING_LOCAL_PATH, "SampleAppFile"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    writeFileContents(newFile, "", "UTF-8"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

    // Pend an add
    // The encoding is passed as null and the add will detect the encoding
    // of the file
    workspace.pendAdd(new String[] {
        newFile.getAbsolutePath()
    }, false, ENCODING, LockLevel.UNCHANGED, GetOptions.NONE, PendChangesOptions.NONE);

    // Checkin the pending change
    final int cs = checkinPendingChanges(workspace, "Adding a sample file"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    System.out.println("Added file " + newFile.getAbsolutePath() + " in CS# " + cs); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

    return newFile;
}

public static void editFile(final Workspace workspace, final File file) {
    // Pend edit
    final ItemSpec fileSpec = new ItemSpec(file.getAbsolutePath(), RecursionType.NONE);
    workspace.pendEdit(
        new ItemSpec[] {
            fileSpec
    },
        LockLevel.UNCHANGED,
        ENCODING,

        GetOptions.NONE,
        PendChangesOptions.NONE);

    // Edit the file
    writeFileContents(file, "Edited this file at " + new Date().toString(), "UTF-8"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

    // Checkin the pending change
    final int cs = checkinPendingChanges(workspace, "Editing the sample file"); //$NON-NLS-1$

    System.out.println("Edited file " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " in CS# " + cs); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
}
```

These are my questions

I was able  to successfully add a new file to the  remote server  , but am not able to edit an existing remote file .

If i call editFile followed by  addFile method it will get updated  , but i dont want to add enw file every time ,what i want is to fetch  the latest version of the buils-main.xml file from server and make changes and do the  check in.

Also after creating the  workspace in local path i couldnt see it in that path , is that the correct behavior ?

Could anyone Please help me on this?

Comment: Do you get any error when you edit a file? After create a workspace, did you perform `Get latest`?

Comment: No , am not getting any errors , and I have called getlatest before editing file. While debugging I could see that in the editFile method after the pendEdit method while calling check impending changes , in that method the pending changes are return as null so it won’t check in the changes .

Comment: What's the meaning of "after creating the  workspace in local path i couldnt see it in that path"? Do you mean you can't see files gotten in this workspace?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT yes , am expecting a folder with files after the method call createAndMapworkspace(), is that the correct behaviour?

Comment: Not only map workspace, you also need to perform a `Get` to get files into the workspace.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT after the createAndMapworkspace method am calling getLatest method , which has the workspace.get() , but after that call so no change ,

Comment: Yes , you are correct , in the createAndMappingworkspace method I called workspace.get , which creates a folder in the local path . And after that the editFile method shows value in the pending changes , So the issue was no files exist locally .thank you it really helped.

Comment: I have added one more question regarding running shared query , could you please check that too?

Comment: You could open a new case, and our team will check it soon.

Comment: I have already added the case : https://stackoverflow.com/q/49978324/8243973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to edit a file that is version controlled by TFS, you need to get the file in a workspace and edit it locally, and then check in the modified file to TFS. I'm not familiar with Java code, I would add c# code for your reference.

1. Create a workspace for the folder that you want to edit:

-

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace TestCaseProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
            var versioncontrols = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            var workspace = versioncontrols.CreateWorkspace("test", "Cece Dong");

            String ServerFolder = @"$/ScrumProject/TestCaseProject";
            String LocalFolder = @"E:\test";

            WorkingFolder workfolder = new WorkingFolder(ServerFolder, LocalFolder);
            workspace.CreateMapping(workfolder);

            workspace.Get();


        }
    }
}
```

2. Use [Workspace.PendEdit Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb143253(v=vs.120)) to edit file that have got from TFS to workspace.
3. Use [Workspace.CheckIn Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb143239(v=vs.120)) to check in the pending changes.

Check the blog below for more details:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/03/10/team-foundation-version-control-client-api-example-for-tfs-2010-and-newer/

Or you can refer to this case to use TFS rest api to update files:

[Updating a file using REST Api Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703475/updating-a-file-using-rest-api-visual-studio-team-services)